# Rails, setting multiple non-database attributes from one method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm a new RoR user and I'm running into some serious ruby logic problems. I done some PHP before and know exactly what I want to do, and how to do it in PHP, but it has taken me hours and I'm no closer to solving it in Rails.

I'll try to outline my intended outcome.

I have a database model, sailing, which has users. Each user has a birthday, language spoken, name, etc.

I want to create my business logic in the model. For example, for a sailing object, I want to be able to call a method in my view that shows the total users on the sailing, I want to be able to show the top 3 languages spoken by those users, and gather the age data into age(0-12, 13-18, 19-29, etc..).

I have been using attr_accessor to add non-database attributes to my model. Below I'll outline some pseudo code defining what I am trying to do.

```
def gather_data
  self.travelling_parties.flat_map do |party|
    party.party_registers.map do |reg|
      reg.user.detailed_user # Returns an array of all my users (working as intended)
      ** Count up users and set to non-database attribute **
      ** Calculate age of users and set three non-database attributes to the largest 3 age groupings **
      ** Count languages and set three non-database attributes to the largest 3 languages
end
```

Ruby methods do not seem to allow me to set multiple variables in the same method. When I do, it seems to 'return' prematurely.

Is there any way I can do this logic in the model? Or what is what I'm trying to do even possible in Ruby?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I thought I'd update my question to try and make things more clear. The following code is in the **view**, but I want to move it to the **model**.

```
<% hash = Hash.new(0) %>
<% sailing.primary_language.each { |language| hash[language] += 1 } %>
<%= debug hash %> # Example output, English: 2 French: 3 German:1
<%= hash.max_by{ |k,v| v}[0] %> # Example output, French
```

The idea is that I'm setting each string into the hash, and if it exists, I'm increasing the value by one. I assume the best practice in Ruby is to do this in the model, but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

Cheers.

Comment: I am interested to know the answer as for now I do this logic in the view directly.  Which probably stresses the server (to what extent, I am not sure)

Comment: Aptorian, you should read these first. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: Thanks Szilard. I had a quick look, and I don't see anything about how to do what I require. I need to search through, for example, 20 users, count up all the languages they speak, and set 3 variables with the highest 3 languages. Do I need to make a separate scope for each language I need to search for (over 15)? ex. where('language == Spanish') It seems cumbersome when this task is so easy to do in PHP.

Comment: can you post the actual code in your method you had that was not setting the values and returning early? Are you perhaps setting your non database attributes like this attribute = value instead of using @ symbol like @attribute = value ? Its definitely possible to set multiple attributes and values in a single method. You can even return multiple values from a single method if you wanted. If your able to post a more specific error I'll add an answer tomorrow